# Get page block table to next page

Tags: visualforce, css, pageblocktable

[image]I am creating and pdf page which is having a Page block table. I am having about 40 + items to display on it. My table is getting break in between.
I want to display it on another page with with same header. Is their any attribute that i can use?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a specific style attribute that creates page breaks at desired locations on the page.

```
<div style="page-break-before: always" />
```

Will move everything that appears after this DIV onto the next page.

There are also other similar page-break properties, you can see how  they all work [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/).

Also note that pageblock table is not recommended to be used in a PDF, you better off replacing that with a normal HTML table using `apex:repeat`'s.  There is more information on what Visualforce elements are safe to use in a PDF [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm#kanchor1017).

Comment: But <div style="page-break-before: always" /> will move all the content to next page which generates an unnecessary space.

Comment: Check out here how to add header/footer on all your pages - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US